# How do I make a React prop only required when used in the context of a Container component with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've been trying to fix this Typescript error I'm getting for some time now.

I've created a sandbox to illustrate the problem. We have

1. An `App` component (this wraps everything)
2. A 'wrapper' component (`AddDateContainer`) - this renders it's children and renders either a timestamp string next to each child or the year
   depending on whether the child has a `yearOnly` prop passed to it
3. A `Text` component - this is a super dumb component that simply renders the `textToRender` prop passed to it

The problem I am getting is that Typescript is complaining about me sending a `yearOnly` prop to the `Text` component because it is not included in `Text`'s interface. I'd rather not include it in `Text`'s interface since it only going to be seen when used within the `AddDateContainer` component.

How can I tell typescript to ignore the `yearOnly` prop in this case?

*this example is pretty arbitrary. I have created this for illustration purposes. The real use case is a lot more valid*

Code,

```
import React from "react";

interface TextInterface {
  textToRender: string;
}

const Text = ({ textToRender }: TextInterface) => {
  return <span>{textToRender}</span>;
};

const AddDateContainer = ({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactElement | React.ReactElement[];
}) => {
  const renderDate = (yearOnly: boolean) => {
    const date = new Date();
    const dateToRender = yearOnly ? date.getFullYear() : date.getTime();
    return <span>{dateToRender}</span>;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        /**
         * IMPORTANT
         * HERE WE ARE REMOVING THE yearOnly prop because it was only needed
         * for the Container.
         * How can we get Typescript to stop complaining!?
         */
        const { format, ...originalProps } = child?.props;
        return (
          <span>
            {React.cloneElement(child, originalProps)}{" "}
            {renderDate(child.props.yearOnly)}
          </span>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <AddDateContainer>
        <Text yearOnly textToRender="I love this" />
      </AddDateContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you want to have `yearOnly` as one of `Text`'s props, then there's no getting around adding it to the `TextInterface`. However, why not just add a second component here, that will be rendered using the `renderDate` function conditionally, depending on *its* `yearOnly` prop?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't add the prop to the higher order component? Something like this:

```js
interface TextInterface {
  textToRender: string;
}

const Text = ({ textToRender }: TextInterface) => <span>{textToRender}</span>;

interface AddDateHocProps extends PropsWithChildren<{}> {
  readonly yearOnly: boolean;
}

const AddDateHoc = ({ children, yearOnly }: AddDateHocProps) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const dateToRender = yearOnly ? date.getFullYear() : date.getTime();

  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => (
        <span>
          {child}
          <span>{dateToRender}</span>;
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <AddDateHoc yearOnly>
        <Text textToRender="I love this" />
      </AddDateHoc>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the example was pretty arbitrary I anticipate having a multitude of props passed in doing various thing and various different amount of children going into the HOC. 

I need the flexibility that I can pass any component into the HOC and essentially pass a  multitude of props into the children as the HOC grows in complexity

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not functionally distinct from this:

```
import React from "react";

interface TextInterface {
  textToRender: string;
}

const Text = ({ textToRender }: TextInterface) => {
  return <span>{textToRender}</span>;
};

const FormattedDate = ({
  yearOnly
}) => {
    const date = new Date();
    const dateToRender = yearOnly ? date.getFullYear() : date.getTime();
    return <span>{dateToRender}</span>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Text yearOnly textToRender="I love this" />
      <FormattedDate yearOnly />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the example was pretty arbitrary I anticipate having a multitude of props passed in doing various thing and various different amount of children going into the HOC.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanks for the response. I've found something which isn't quite what I wanted but is flexible enough that I think I'm happy with it. I've used a generic in the Text interface. It feels like what I was trying to do i.e. make the Container component handle the types might not be possible.

Here is the change,

```
interface TextInterface {
  textToRender: string;
}

const Text = <T extends TextInterface>(props: T) => {
  const { textToRender } = props;
  return <span>{textToRender}</span>;
};
```

The `T` makes it so the `yearOnly` can get through (any other props I might want to add for the benefit of the Container) will get through without me explicitly writing those props into the interface.

Comment: This works, but you're undermining the compiler's ability to notice problems with your code. Now you'll be able to pass *anything* to `Text` and the compiler won't complain, even if what you passed was unintentional or of the wrong type. Can you explain a bit about what kind of work this HOC does? It seems like you're heading down a needlessly complex path for something that may have a simpler, more idiomatic and `React`ish solution..

Comment: @M-N the code is essentially like the `<Switch />` component in React router. You specify the 'views' in my case (I don't want to actually have url routing) within a container.

Looks like this,
```
<Container>
   <Something view={{vkey: 'something' , default:true, ...some other stuff}}>
   <SomeOtherComponent view={{key:'someOtherComponent, ...some other stuff}}/>

</Container>

```